# S-57 import in QGIS; selecting one layer from multiple files?

Tags: qgis, s-57

I am building a nautical basemap that is build out of multiple S-57 cells (*.000 files).

I go through to following steps:

1. I download the files from a server and copy all the files (65 files) in a folder
2. I open QGIS and go to folder in "Panel Browser"
3. I select all the files and drag them to my "Panal Layers"
4. I pop-up opens "Selecteer toe te voegen vectorlagen" (that should translate to: Select vectorlayers to be opened"
5. I manually, handselect, the layer i want, which is: DEPARE.
6. After the 1st popup, 64 more automaticly open, so I repeat the process 64 times.
7. After all this is done. I have all my DEPARE layers on screen.
8. I select all the DEPARE layers (vectorlayers) and merge them to one shapefile.

Is there a way in QGIS to prevent step 6 of the above?

I would like to add all the files to my project but have QGIS automaticly pull the DEPARE layer from all the files, so I don't have to handselect them 65 times.

[image: example basemap on big scale]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.  I think you should focus your question on "In the importing process I hand pick the DEPARE and DEPCTN layers from the cells" because that sounds like it is manual and could benefit from automation.

Comment: sounds like an ogr2ogr job to me